# Android :: Resizable Circle Google Maps API ver 2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to draw a resizable circle around a center marker using [Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) API.

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689))
     .radius(10000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

The code should allow the user to change the radius of the circle either by the hand gestures or may be by dragging another pin on the circumference of the circle. The center marker should always be still. The [Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) as per google API does not provide any resizable or draggable property(As for example in Marker : (markerOptions.draggable(true))).I found a javascript Implementation of the above problem. Please find the below link. Please help in the implementation the above problem in android (Java).
http://web3o.blogspot.fr/2010/05/google-maps-dynamically-movable-and.html
[image: Example]